# JQuery onClick auto-generated table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am auto populating a table from JSON data that a retrieve via $.getJSON. call.

when i click ant  i want to show an alert.

this is my code.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <img id="titleimage" border="0" src="images/title.png">
        </div>

        <div id="sub-container">
            <div id ="video_container">
                <h1>HTML5 local video file player example</h1>
                <div id="message"></div>
                <input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
                <video id="match_video" controls autoplay></video>
            </div>
            <div id="log_container">
                <table id="chart"class="masterTooltip" title="RaboPro12 League Table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="stats_container"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON("php/getLog.php", function(result) {
    //var data = $.parseJSON(result);

    $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
        var fname = obj.first_name;
        var sname = obj.surname;
        var allName = fname + " " + sname;
        var time = obj.time;
        var event = obj.event;
        $('<tr id ="row"></tr').html('<td>' + time + '</td><td>' + event + '</td><td>' + allName + '</td>)').appendTo('#chart');
    });
}); 

$('.row').click(function() {
    alert("row clicked");
});
```

});

here is snippet of html after tableis populated.

[image]

the row click is not triggered for some reason.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your rows have an ID of "row" yet you are targeting a class of "row" in your jQuery. Change the IDs to classes and it will work.

Comment: @ChrisMowbray Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) because when the event handler is registered all the target elements are not there in the dom, some of them are created dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click', '.row', function () {
    alert("row clicked");
});
```